# SharePoint - multiple time and user stamped comments per list row and friendly named lookups

Tags: sharepoint, list, document, lookup-tables

I suspect these are some of the limiations of SharePoint.

Does anything in the SharePoint UI allow for a column to be added to a list that enable users to enter multiple time and user stamped entries to a single custom list row? For example like  a comment column?

And on the subject of connecting two list to each other. Ideally, we would connect (lookup) two lists by the list ID, having one list look up to another by a friendly name, but then store the list id. This does not seeam like it's availble in sharePoint.. is it?

Thanks.

Comment: For this Q&A site you're better off keeping to one question per post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharePoint List Superpowers (see Issue List – Comments History)](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/sharepoint-list-superpowers/)

To setup this style of comments you need to

- Turn on **versioning** on the list
  Settings > List Settings > Versioning
- Change (or add a new) **Multiple Lines of Text** field and set **Append Changes to Existing Text**

Answer (score 1):

The Comments field is the only field I'm aware of that has the append behavior. Of course, version control gives you some visibility to changes on any field type.

In SharePoint 2007, when you add a lookup, the list actually does keep track of the lookup ID internally, despite what it presents. For example, if you look up a title, you'll find that the raw value stored in the list is a composition of the lookup item ID and the title. When you link to your list in access, list tables are still joined by IDs rather than the friendly text.

Comment: Thanks. I need to test to see what happens when the friendly column is changed at the source List row. Also, If I set up a lookup to a list column from a Doc lib using the friendly name, is there any way filter a View of the Doc Lib by the ID of the list row being used? I'm sorry I do have a related post on this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676113/sharepoint-modifying-customizing-editform-aspx-of-doc-lib-breaks-upload-functi . Thanks.

Comment: @cyberpine - Filtering by the ID (when you lookup another column) is not possible, *at least, in the list view web part*. Because you can filter by ID when you link to Access, I must assume it can be done using something else, but I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: I just checked and the ID of the source table on the lookup does not list in Designer's Dataview either. I'm not sure if there is way to get to it with XSLT or CAML. I did find this and going to try. Thanks.